# How do I completely remove devexpress from the computer?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I uninstalled devexpress from the control panel. Later, when I wanted to install it again from the installation wizard, I saw that the devexpress plugins were still installed. How do I solve this situation?

I deleted the devexpress records from the registry and deleted the folders I found related to devexpress. But the result did not change

[image: Setup wizard]

Comment: You mean the Visual Studio Extensions with plugins? Visual Studio is completely self contained it uses a private registry for example to not fiddle with the common windows registry. Just use the Visual Studio functionality to remove Extensions (the Extension/Manage Extensions menu).

Comment: What version are you trying to install? What was the last major version you had installed? What is the last version you held a license to?